# Differential equation $y''+3y'+2y=0$ and $y(x)>0$ when $x>0$, then which of the following is correct?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Given a differential equation $y''+3y'+2y=0$ and $y(x)>0$ when $x>0$, then which of the following is correct?
>
> (A) y is strictly increasing
>
> (B) y is strictly decreasing
>
> (C) when $x>0$, $y$ is increasing; when $x<0$, $y$ is decreasing
>
> (D) when $x<0$, $y$ is increasing; when $x>0$, $y$ is decreasing
>
> (E) y is periodic

The solution to this ODE is $y(x)=C_1 e^{-x} +C_2 e^{-2x}$. Then $y'=-C_1e^{-x}-2C_2e^{-2x}$, from which I can't tell the positivity of $y'$.

I feel that $C_1$ should be positive but $C_2$ can be negative. But I don't know how to make a formal statement.

Comment: i think $C_1>0$and$C_2>0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C_2$ can not be negative, because
$$y(x)=C_1 e^{-x} +C_2 e^{-2x}=C_2\left(e^{-x}+\dfrac{C_1}{2C_2}\right)^2- \dfrac{C_1^2}{4C_2}>0$$
concludes that
$$\left(e^{-x}+\dfrac{C_1}{2C_2}\right)^2< \dfrac{C_1^2}{4C_2^2}$$
and this shows $e^{-x}<0$. Then $y'=-y-C_2e^{-2x}<0$.

Comment: Do you mean $y'<0$ for all $x$? When $x>0$, it is no doubt that $y'<0$. When $x<0$, how do you know $y'<0$?

Comment: I wrote this with condition $y>0$ when $x>0$.